# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float' in scipy.interpolate.interp1d

Tags: python

i have this error when trying to interpolate with interp1d

```
usecols = [i for i in range(0,3)]
VLE_data = pd.read_csv('VLE data.txt',delimiter = ' ',header=1,usecols=usecols)

VLE_data = VLE_data.set_index('methyl')
VLE_data = VLE_data.drop('methyl',axis=0)
VLE_data = VLE_data.reset_index()
T_data = VLE_data.loc[:,'methyl']
T_data1 = VLE_data.loc[0:19,'methyl']
T_data2 = VLE_data.loc[20:37,'methyl']
T_data3 = VLE_data.loc[38:,'methyl']

x_data = VLE_data.loc[:,'acetate']
x_data1 = VLE_data.loc[0:19,'acetate']
x_data2 = VLE_data.loc[20:37,'acetate']
x_data3 = VLE_data.loc[38:,'acetate']

y_data = VLE_data.loc[:,'(1)']
y_data1 = VLE_data.loc[0:19,'(1)']
y_data2 = VLE_data.loc[20:37,'(1)']
y_data3 = VLE_data.loc[38:,'(1)']

VLE_Pdata = pd.read_csv('VLE data.txt',delimiter = ' ')
P_data = VLE_Pdata.loc['methyl','\u03B31']

xnew = np.linspace(0,1,10)
ynew = np.linspace(0,1,10)

funP1x = interp1d(x_data1,T_data1,kind='linear')
funP3x = interp1d(x_data2,T_data2,kind='linear')
funP7x = interp1d(x_data3,T_data3,kind='linear')
funP1y = interp1d(y_data1,T_data1,kind='linear')
funP3y = interp1d(y_data2,T_data2,kind='linear')
funP7y = interp1d(y_data3,T_data3,kind='linear')

T1new = funP1x(xnew)
```

i got this error as result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\VLE.py", line 46, in <module>
    T1new = funP1x(xnew)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\polyint.py", line 78, in __call__
    y = self._evaluate(x)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 675, in _evaluate
    y_new = self._call(self, x_new)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 605, in _call_linear
    x_new_indices = searchsorted(self.x, x_new)

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in searchsorted

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 1348, in searchsorted
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'searchsorted', v, side=side, sorter=sorter)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 67, in _wrapfunc
    return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 44, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

what cause this error?

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try to check the contents of the `x_data1`, `T_data1` etc.? Does it contain strings, or floats? Or both? Do you understand the error message? What do you expect the interpolation process to do if there are strings in your data?

Comment: Sorry i am new to python, i think my data are floats. I am trying to interpolate the data to get T1new with xnew and ynew